# Access to an input element in jQuery by using a variable for the ID

Tags: jquery, input, syntax

Im trying to make input text required based on radio button choice. The input text ID is Js variable (concatenated to loop var).
How can i access to it via jquery ?

this is my code  : 
JS :

```
var submyform = "<br> SubstantialOwner: <br> "
+"Personne physique <input type='radio' onclick='javascript:PPMCheck();' name='PPM[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]' id='PP[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]'> "
            +"Personne Morale  <input type='radio' onclick='javascript:PPMCheck();' name='PPM[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]' id='PM[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]' checked><br> "                 
 +"Last name (obligatoire pou les PP) :"

              +"<input type ='text' name='subln[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]'  value=''  id='ln[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]' >"
```

My jquery :

```
 <script>
        $("#option1").click(function() {
            $("#required_later").prop("required", false);
            $("#required_later").prop("disabled", true);
        });
        $("#option2").click(function() {
            $("#required_later").prop("required", true);
            $("#required_later").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#required_later").focus();
        });
    </script>
```

How can i change "#option1" by the id of my radio which is :  `id='PP[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]'`

Comment: Are you sure `$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms` works? have you inspected your elements? Also, common use of `$` prefixed variables wil tell every developer in the world that `$something` is a jQuery Element. Whereas in your code  (supposedly) those are not.

Comment: Where are `#option1` and `#option2`  Elements?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes it works! the piece of code above make user create forms as much forms as he wants (Nested forms). #option1 is the equivalent of id : 'PP[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]'. I did not know how to acces to it that why i called it #option1

Comment: It makes no sense to set `required = false` on an anyways disabled element. Do you agree?

Comment: Where is your `#required_later` element?

Comment: You cannot have duplicated ID in a single page, you know that, right? Use classes instead.

Comment: #required_later a also a name i gave to input  id='ln[x"+$subforwhichaccount+$subcountForms+"]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing  the `readonly` (or `disabled`) - you could change the `hidden` Element property.

Add `data-target-personne="NNN"` to store the Number "ID". Than using JS, on radio change, get that `.data("target-personne")` number and use it to do stuff with classes that are suffixed by *_`NNN`* i.e: `someClassName_NNN`

Use the `value` attribute for your radios. Than you can check for boolean using

```
this.checked && this.value === 'physique'
```

<sub>Live example:</sub>

```js
const submyform = (function(n) {
  return () => {
    n++;
    return `
      <fieldset>
        <label>
          Personne Physique
          <input type="radio" name="personne_${n}" value="physique" data-target-personne="${n}">
        </label>
        <label>
          Personne Morale
          <input type="radio" name="personne_${n}" value="morale" data-target-personne="${n}" checked>
        </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="physique_${n}" name="prenom_${n}" placeholder="Prénom" hidden>
        <input type="text" class="physique_${n}" name="nomdefam_${n}" placeholder="Nom de famille" hidden>
        <input type="text" class="morale_${n}" name="nom_${n}" placeholder="Nom">
        <input type="text" class="morale_${n}" name="tva_${n}" placeholder="T.V.A.">
      </fieldset>
     `;
  };
}( 0 )); // start `n` count at 0 (or use a database counter)

jQuery($ => {

  const $formulaire = $('#formulaire');
  const $inserer = $('#inserer');
  
  // Create new fields
  $inserer.on('click', (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $formulaire.append(submyform());
  });

  // Handle fields
  $formulaire.on('change', '[data-target-personne]', function() {
  
    const n = $(this).data('target-personne');
    const $physique = $(`.physique_${n}`);
    const $morale = $(`.morale_${n}`);
    const cestPhysique = this.checked && this.value === 'physique';

    $physique.prop({
      hidden: !cestPhysique,
      required: cestPhysique
    });
    
    $morale.prop({
      hidden: cestPhysique,   // the inverse logic
      required: !cestPhysique // the inverse logic
    });

    if (!cestPhysique) $physique.val(''); // Reset inputs values
  });

});
```

```html
<form id="formulaire"></form>
<button id="inserer">Insérer une personne</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

if you want you can always use the `readonly` property instead of `hidden` - but I like cleaner UI.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. My problem is with input name that are variable. In the example you give, imagine having many copies of input "prenom" and input"nomfamille" in the same "formulaire" (user can create as much copies as he wants). "prenom"  then should be unique, for this you should concatenate the name to a loop var : <input name="prenom+$i"> . How to use this "prenom+$i" in jQuery selectors ?